# Vertically Align Bootstrap Checkbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically align checkboxes for a column of checkboxes + labels. Ideally, I'd like the elements to be in the center of the page but with the checkboxes themselves vertically aligned.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12 pagination-centered">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">asdfasdf</label>
  </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">sdfasdf</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">asfdasdf</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">asdfasdf</label>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

This is one way to do it

```
<div class="row">  
    <div class="col-md-4 "></div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align:center">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">asdfasdf</label>
  </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">sdfasdf</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">asfdasdf</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">asdfasdf</label>
  </div>
 </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 "></div>
</div>
```

Another way to do this is:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">asdfasdf</label>
  </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">sdfasdf</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">asfdasdf</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">asdfasdf</label>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Both produce the same result

Answer (score 5):

Simply add these styles

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.span12.pagination-centered {
    margin: 25px auto;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.span12.pagination-centered {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12 pagination-centered">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">asdfasdf</label>
  </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">sdfasdf</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">asfdasdf</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">asdfasdf</label>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this,

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row vertical-align">                  
        <div class="col-xs-6"> ... </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"> ... </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.vertical-align {
     align-items: center;
}
```